# Powershell to enable Internet Explorer downloads

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2012

To enable downloads in the Internet Explorer for Windows 2012 R2 I must:

Settings > Internet options > Security > Custom Level > Enable downloads

[image]

How am I able to do this with a powershell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way...

A value of 3 disables it and 0 enables it.  Also, you have to set the Zone (the last value in the path); in this case I set the Trusted Sites zone (2).  The Zone numbers are below...

1=Local Intranet Zone
2=Trusted sites Zone
3=Internet Zone
4=Restricted Sites Zone

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet 
Settings\Zones\2" -Name "1803" -Value 3
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet 
Settings\Zones\2" -Name "1803" -Value 3
```